# IQueryable convert to list

Tags: c#, iqueryable

Something so simple, but my head is hurting over it, I'm sure I can write this in one line when converting, but how?

```
IQueryable<ion> ions =FindAllions();

List<ionFormViewModel> ionFormViewModels = new List<ionFormViewModel>();

foreach (ion ion in ions)
{
     ionFormViewModel ionFormViewModel = new ionFormViewModel(ion);
     ionFormViewModels.Add(ionFormViewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<ionFormViewModel> ionFormViewModels
    = ions.Select(i => new ionFormViewModel(i)).ToList();
```

The [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) extension method allows you to project a new value into a new sequence for each value in your current sequence.  Basically it gives you the ability to generate sequences from other sequences with a transformation step in between.

Then the [`Enumerable.ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) extension method simply creates a new `List<T>` from the `Select` method's resulting `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ionFormViewModels = ions.Select(ion => new ionFormViewModel(ion)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ionFormViewModel> ionFormViewModels = ions.Select(i => new ionFormViewModel(i)).ToList()
```